# Reactor - Flux.fromIterable(list).parallel - load test

Tags: spring-webflux

This is an example of a reactor parallel execution. It works fine when we run the service with little load. However, when we stress the service it does not respond as expected. It starts to take longer to response as soon as we reach 40 request/sec (longer means more than 5 sec).

Here it is the piece of the code that is causing problems :)

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getAccountWithBalances(final ServerRequest request) {
    final List<String> accounts = List.of("account-1", "account-2", "account-3", "account-4");

    return Flux.fromIterable(accounts)
            .log(Thread.currentThread().getName())
            .parallel()
            .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .flatMap(account ->
                    webClient.get().uri("/stubs/accounts")
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(Object.class)
            )
            .doOnError(throwable -> LOGGER.error("Error during runtime ", throwable))
            .sequential()
            .collectList()
    .flatMap(accountsWithBalances ->
            ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).bodyValue(accountsWithBalances));

}
```

This is the repo where I have the code:
https://github.com/EstefaniaExamples/webflux-load-test

This is the repo where the wiremock server is:
https://github.com/EstefaniaExamples/wiremock-standalone-server

This topic is really fun :), I´m still starting with this kind of things, so any help is wellcome.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: please post the relevant code snippets so that people can reproduce it, no one wants to dig around in a gitrepo to try to find your problems. You can include the git repo as a compliment to your original question, but update your question with code examples. voted to close `needs debugging details`

Comment: Ok, sorry. I did not want to bother anyone. I will edit the post adding a piece of code.

Comment: retracted my vote, now what is your question? what is the expected outcome, what kind of performance are you expecting, when you are claiming this is slow, in comparison to what? to me the bottle neck seems to be wiremock, and not webflux. Especially when wiremock is not designed for load testing. And no one can answer this question since we have no idea of specs, we have nothing to compare against, what is wiremock expected to produce? what is your app expected to produce?

Comment: This is just an example I'm working on. Trying to understand how this works and test if it is capable to handle lots of requests. As you could see the code is very simple, and the request calls the wiremock server that basically returns a json (nothing else). So, I think the response time shouldn't be longer than 2 seconds. Base on your comments, it seems the code is fine, doesn't it? And the problem is the mock server that is not able to handle all those requests, but in this case, shouldn't I see anything in the wiremock logs?

Comment: if the code is "fine" is opinion based, does it handle requests, yes, most effectively, maybe, maybe not. You do not gain much using `parallel` execution considering the work you are having it do. Since the event loop in reactor is single threaded. `Parallel` execution is usually (in theory) only beneficial if you have CPU heavy execution that needs to use the cores for calculations. Your code atm. schedules work using the boundedElastic scheduler which is already using multiple cores. So using "parallel" here is probably not necessary.

Comment: reactor has something called `event loops` which is the number of threads as cores the machine has. These `event loop threads` are used to just process events. Then you have `schedulers`, which are (most likely) threads that schedule work on the respective `event loop`. `boundedElastic` is a `scheduler` that dynamically creates a maximum (per default) 10 threads per core that can schedule work on each cores `event loop`. If all `scheduling threads` are busy, up to 100 000 events can be queued until a scheduling thread becomes available to schedule that event to be processed by that core.

Comment: all this is done under the hood without using `parallel` so most likely you dont need `parallel` and `sequential`

Comment: how do you know that the code you have provided is what is causing your "problem" and not wiremock, or your computer specs, or any other thing and im not talking about what your "feeling" is, im talking about `what do you know?`

Comment: You can try to tweak Wiremock settings. There are some recommended settings for performance testing purpose: http://wiremock.org/docs/configuration/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you both! It is really appreciate, I've being investigating the issue, thanks to your comments I saw the path. And yes, the wiremock server was causing the issue. I have scaled the replicas and also done some changes in the wiremock server (https://github.com/sagardutta/wiremock-load-test), and I think it is ok the result that I got. So, the code was not causing the issue, this is the good part.

Best regards.